# Why aren't my canvas items not binding properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am in the process of porting a game that I wrote into a user friendly GUI. Please bear with me, as it is my first time playing around with tkinter.

Once the player inputs how many rows/columns he would like to play with, we draw up the gameboard.

If you look at the following code, you see that I assign tags to each square that we create, in the format of 'row, col'

I called .tag_bind to the square located in row 0, column 3. When clicked, it should call the _on_canvas_clicked function. However, when I run the program, it doesn't respond or do anything when I click that square.

```
    gameframe = tkinter.Frame(master = self._dialog_window)
    gameframe.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.W)

    boardWidth = cols * self._sqheight
    boardHeight = rows * self._sqheight
    self.gameboard = Canvas(gameframe, width = boardWidth, height = boardHeight, bg = 'green')
    self.gameboard.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            top = row * self._sqheight
            left = col * self._sqheight
            bottom = row * self._sqheight + self._sqheight -1
            right = col * self._sqheight + self._sqheight -1
            rect = self.gameboard.create_rectangle(left,top,right,bottom,outline='gray',fill='',tags="(row, col)")
            self.gameboard.itemconfig(rect, tags='{},{}'.format(row, col))

    self.gameboard.tag_bind('0,3', '<ButtonPress-1>', self._on_canvas_clicked)
```

`self.gameboard.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_canvas_clicked)` works as intended. But tag_bind does not. I made sure (I think...) that the tags were properly being assigned.

Anyone care to help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind to a rectangle, the event fires when you click on one of the pixels that belongs to a rectangle. Since you're using `fill=""`, the interior of the rectangle has no pixels. Your code actually works if you position your mouse over the border.

You should give your rectangles a fill color if you want to be able to click on them. Or, you can add one binding to a canvas and then use the canvas's ability to find the object(s) nearest the click.

Also, you need to move the `tag_bind` inside the loop if your intention is to add the binding for each rectangle.